# Careers doesn't show education item if date is blank

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

If you leave a blank date in the education field, it does not show up on the final CV. Some of us prefer not to list the exact details, and we should still be able to claim to be educated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed - before, we were requiring *all three* Degree/University/Time Frame (or  Title/Company/Time Frame for Experience) to be present before a section would show up.

Now, only the Degree/Title need be present for a section to be visible.